# Como somar com jQuery dados em uma tabela?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Como obter com jQuery a somatória de todos os campos de `class="subtotal1"` retornados do banco de dados?

```
<?php while($M_P = mysql_fetch_array($Dados_Produtos)) { ?>
    <tr class="somatoria">
        <td><?=utf8_encode($M_P['produto'])?></td>
        <td><?=$M_P['codigo']?></td>
        <td>R$ <span class="subtotal1">29.00</span></td>
        <td><?=$M_P['quantidade']?></td>
        <td>R$ <?=$M_P['taxas']?></td>
        <td>R$ <span class="subtotal2">29.00</span></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Se o valor for dinâmico, você pode criar um array no PHP para usar pelo JS sem necessidade do jQuery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notar que nos dois casos, usei o `subtotal2` como referência, mas a lógica serve para qualquer campo. Também retirei as tags curtas de PHP (`<?=`) , pois não são portáteis, mas é mera sugestão. A formatação dos campos em formato monetário com duas casas fica a cargo de ajustes na solução adotada (e já foge um bocado do escopo).

### Com JQuery:

```js
// Código principal:
$(function() {
    var soma = 0;
    $( ".subtotal2" ).each( function() {
        soma += Number( $( this ).html() );
    } );
    $( "#resultado" ).text( "R$ " + soma );
} );
```

```html
<!-- Trecho HTML para demonstração: -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="somatoria">
        <td>Balao de borracha</td>
        <td>12789</td>
        <td>R$ <span class="subtotal1">29.00</span></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>R$ 2</td>
        <td>R$ <span class="subtotal2">31.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="somatoria">
        <td>CD Maria do Relento</td>
        <td>23419</td>
        <td>R$ <span class="subtotal1">33.00</span></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>R$ 0</td>
        <td>R$ <span class="subtotal2">33.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">TOTAL</td>
        <td id="resultado">?</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Com PHP:

```php
<?php
    $soma = 0;
    while($M_P = mysql_fetch_array($Dados_Produtos)) {
        $subtotal2 = $M_P['preco'] * $M_P['quantidade'] + $M_P['taxas'];
        $soma += $subtotal2;
?>
    <tr class="somatoria">
        <td><?php echo utf8_encode($M_P['produto']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $M_P['codigo']; ?></td>
        <td>R$ <span class="subtotal1"><?php echo $M_P['preco']; ?></span></td>
        <td><?php echo $M_P['quantidade']; ?></td>
        <td>R$ <?php echo $M_P['taxas']; ?></td>
        <td>R$ <span class="subtotal2"><?php echo $subtotal2; ?></span></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"></td>
        <td>R$ <?php echo $soma; ?></td>
```

Comment: Não seria interessante usar o parseInt() nos valores antes de calcular? Só para garantir mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
// criar uma array com os valores
var subTotais = $('.subtotal1').map(function () {
    return parseFloat(this.innerHTML);
}).get();
// somar todos
var total = subTotais.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
// exibir resultado
console.log(total); // resultado
```

```js
var totais = $('.subtotal1').map(function () {
    return parseFloat(this.innerHTML);
}).get();
var total = totais.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
alert(total); // resultado
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="somatoria">
        <td>
            <?=utf8_encode($M_P[ 'produto'])?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?=$M_P[ 'codigo']?>
        </td>
        <td>R$ <span class="subtotal1">29.00</span>

        </td>
        <td>
            <?=$M_P[ 'quantidade']?>
        </td>
        <td>R$
            <?=$M_P[ 'taxas']?>
        </td>
        <td>R$ <span class="subtotal2">29.00</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="somatoria">
        <td>
            <?=utf8_encode($M_P[ 'produto'])?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?=$M_P[ 'codigo']?>
        </td>
        <td>R$ <span class="subtotal1">29.00</span>

        </td>
        <td>
            <?=$M_P[ 'quantidade']?>
        </td>
        <td>R$
            <?=$M_P[ 'taxas']?>
        </td>
        <td>R$ <span class="subtotal2">29.00</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```